# Uzbl browser - how to hide title bar

Tags: raspbian, web-browsers

I am trying to use uzbl browser in kiosk mode just like `midori -a www.facebook.com -e Full screen` (no title bar, no status bar, full screen). I like this browser as it provides a flexible way to control programmatically from external app through redirected `stdin`.

What I could do so far was:

- `set show_status=0` (hide status bar)
- `set geometry=maximized` (full screen)

But how can I hide title bar? I have played with geometry variable hoping I can make a window bigger than actual screen size or adjust Y offset but had no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uzbl browser (as of Sep 2013) may not have fullscreen mode but found one way using openbox (version 3.5.0) configuration:

Edit '~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml' file so that its 'applications' section to have

```
  <application name="uzbl*">
    <fullscreen>yes</fullscreen>  
  </application>
```

Then `openbox --reconfigure`.
Now uzbl browser window is shown in fullscreen mode showing no title bar, no task bar.